# Symmetry of cardioid in parametric equation

Tags: curves

The parametric equation of cardioid is $$(x(t),y(t))=(a(2\cos t-\cos 2t), a(2\sin t-\sin 2t)).$$ How To underdstand *from parametric equation* that this curve is symmetric about $x$-axis?

Can anyone explain that in detail?

Comment: Hint: $x$ is an even function of $t$ and $y$ an odd one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Yes it is true that $x(-t)=x(t)$ and $y(-t)=-y(t)$. But how it can help to my question?

Comment: What is symmetry about $x$ axis ?

Comment: I meant that the graph of function is symmetric with regard to $x$-axis, i.e. $(x,y)$ lies in graph then $(x,-y)$ also lies.

Comment: Now merge your last two comments.

Comment: @YvesDaoust,  if $(x(t),y(t))\in \Gamma$ and $x(-t)=x(t), \ y(-t)=-y(t)$. Then: $(x(t),y(t))=(x(-t), -y(-t))\in \Gamma$. But how to derive that $(x(t), -y(t)) \in \Gamma$?

Comment: It is in front of your eyes. Try harder.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please can you tell me whether my method is even applicable here.?

Comment: @samjoe: approximately because $x$ may not be a univocal function of $y$. But the question is so simple (!)

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Unfortunately my efforts are worthless. I am not able to show that $(x(t),-y(t))$ also $\in \Gamma$

Comment: @RFZ Put $-t$ in place of $t$ !

Comment: @samjoe, suppose $f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ lies on graph and if we put $-t$ instead of $t$ we get $f(-t)=(x(-t),y(-t))=(x(t), -y(t))$ (due to parity of functions). But why $f(-t)$ also lies on graph? Maybe it is simple but I can't comprehend it.

Comment: @RFZ You have imposed no condition on $t$, so it can be *any* real number!

Comment: If I am not mistaken $t$ is any real so $f(-t)$ also lies on graph and hence it's symmetrical about $x$-axis. Right?

Comment: @RFZ Yes thats all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the parity of the functions, $(x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$ are reached for $t$ and $-t$.

Comment: You are correct, this question was so simple!